# WCF service errors after installing WindowsXP updates

Tags: wcf, windows-update

Greetings,

today before I start working on my application I updated my WinXP. After all updates have been installed my WCF service stop working. There is a following error when I try to open service.svc file in the browser:

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/bindings: Could not load type 'System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.Configuration.ExtendedProtectionPolicyElement' from assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Source Error: 


Line 131:       </behaviors>
Line 132:
Line 133:       <bindings>
Line 134:           <wsHttpBinding>
Line 135:               <binding name="MyWSHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
```

The colleague of mine tried to run the same service before update and it works fine. He has the same problem after installing updates. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I can't reproduce, sorry - both WCF 3.5 and 4 .svcs worked fine for me after the upgrade without a recompile :-/ It sounds like you're running 3.5 and you have two assemblies now out-of-sync: there were two .NET 3.5SP1 updates, KB982168 and KB979909 - did you definitely install both? Failing that, I don't have any good ideas - there's the usual `ServiceModelReg -i` which is worth trying but that doesn't look like the problem.

Comment: it seems like I don't have KB982168. Where I can find it? I can't find it on MS updates site.

Comment: even after installing above update the problem still occurs

Comment: @niao :-( I'd contact Microsoft support then. Given lots of people have this I expect it's a bug and a non-chargeable incident (I did the same for a Silverlight SDK problem). In the meantime I guess it's worth rolling back the KB979909 to see if that fixes this for you but I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: thank you. I have already rolled back this update and I can work again. But obviously this problem has to be fixed.

Comment: In the interest of further documentation, I also just saw this issue after allowing XP to update today. And uninstalling the two patches referenced, KB982168 and KB979909, did indeed make everything work properly again. Thanks, SO!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, the problem indeed seems to come from the update KB982168 and only on 2003 servers. Microsoft support suspects a bug in the HttpTransportSecurity constructor that tries to instantiate a ExtendedProtectionPolicy object, but this class does not exist in system.dll on a 2003 server (or XP machines) (you can check with reflector). And it is indeed present on the DLL on a 2008 or Vista and above. If the problem is confirmed, I think there will be a hot fix released very soon. Meanwhile it is recommended to not install the update. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: are there any official comments or advices about this issue from Microsoft?

Comment: Not yet, the support told me they'll come back to me in 2 or 3 days with more information.

Comment: Greetings, is there any additional feedback from Microsoft?

Comment: Not yet, they are analysing the logs i provided from my server. They told me that this seems to be a major issue as a lot of people is experiencing the same problem. So i'm very confident that a solution will be released shortly

Answer (score 5):

The problem is caused by an incorrectly behaving component of the path installer.This is present in multiple hotfixes, and may cause an incorrect installation order or skipping installation of a patch.

Here is the hot fix to solve this issue given by Microsoft support team.

- install KB982168, which should reproduce the error.
- Note the version of %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\system.dll (should be 2.0.50727.3053)
- download the KB975954 hotfix:
  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26146
  You would need to pick the package
  corresponding to your OS
  architecture: NDP20SP2-KB975954-x86.exe (MSI), NDP20SP2-KB975954-x64.exe (MSI), NDP20SP2-KB975954-IA64.exe (MSI)
- Install the appropriate hotfix for your OS architecture.
- Run the following command line from an elevated prompt:
  msiexec /f {C09FB3CD-3D0C-3F2D-899A-6A1D67F2073F}
- Check the version of %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\system.dll (Should be 2.0.50727.4443)

I installed this on a test server and it solved the problem.

No doubt that this will be soon integrated on windows update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't mind knowing what running msiexec on that guid actually *did*, but whatever it did, it would appear to have fixed everything. So that's cool.

Comment: msiexec /f is laucnh to repair a product or a package and the GUID cis the GUID of the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2. More info here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/04/16/9553804.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to report that the official KB article for this issue has been posted at the following location: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2262911

The workaround outlined above is correct and is the same workaround that you will find in this KB article.

The patch provided in the KB article has been validated to resolve the installation issue as well as safe for production environments. We will also be publishing in the KB article a Fix-It patch to seamlessly resolve this issue without needing to go through the workaround steps. Given that we have identified the root cause of this issue, all previous hotfixes which cause the installation failure will be updated appropriately.

It is important that WCF applications are unblocked and able to successfully install Windows Update KB # 982167 and/or 982168 on all machines. If you have uninstalled the Windows Update, please follow the KB article to get this update on your machine.

Sorry for this inconvenience.

Thanks,

Erica 
Microsoft Program Manager

Answer (score 3):

I fixed that issue by uninstalling KB976769v2.

Answer (score 1):

I have reported the error to Microsoft. I'll wait for the call from technical support.

Comment: don't worry i will. Meanwhile i'm trying to unistall updates KB982168 to see if it solved the problem as it did for you.

Comment: i unistalled KB979909 and it solved the issue for now as well....
I'm still waiting for microsoft feedback.

Comment: so far : the problem seems to come indeed from the update KB982168 and only on 2003 servers. Microsoft support suspects a bug in the HttpTransportSecurity constructor that tries to instanciate a ExtendedProtectionPolicy object, but this class does not exists in system.dll on a 2003 server (or XP machines) (you can check with reflector). And it is indeed present on the DLL on a 2008 or Vista and above.
If the problem is confirmed, i think there will be a hot fix released very soon. MeanWhile it is recommanded to not install the update. I'll keep you informed.