# WCF Service errors - Could not load type 'System.Security.Authentication

Tags: wcf

Same WCF Service works at another environment but got error in my local, error message -

> Could not load type
>   'System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ExtendedProtectionPolicy'
>   from assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I checked much info, for example - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB975954/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3839 
tried to uninstall KB976769v2. reboot, but failed
tried to install hotfix regarding the same issue, reboot, but still failed.

Please help me out. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I uninstalled KB979909 & KB976769v2 on my Win XP machine, and works now!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004299/wcf-service-errors-after-installing-windowsxp-updates