# Could not load type 'System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ExtendedProtectionPolicy'

Tags: wcf

I recently updated my XP machine now I can't run any of my WCF (.NET 3.5) web apps. It crashes when I call `var wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();` with the following exception:

> Could not load type
>   'System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ExtendedProtectionPolicy'
>   from assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733205/wcf-service-errors-could-not-load-type-system-security-authentication) but it did not help. There are many posts at [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2262911) that do not help either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF service errors after installing WindowsXP updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004299/wcf-service-errors-after-installing-windowsxp-updates)